# Link to a different view of search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a page that shows 3 lists of search results: illustrations, novels, and tags.  I want to allow the user to click a link for each of the lists to see a grid of thumbnails.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to pass the search result objects to a new page. I am only getting the strings of the illustration ids.

The search method of main_controller, and what I'm trying to do to show_illustrations :

```
def search
    @search_criteria = params[:search]
    @novels = Novel.search(params[:search])
    @illustrations = Illustration.search(params[:search])
    @tags = Tag.search(params[:search])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #search_results.html.erb
    end
  end

 def show_illustrations
    @illustrations = params[:illustrations]
 end
```

The partial that shows the list of illustrations in the search results.  The app insists on calling the show method of main even though I assign the action in the link_to statement to 'show_illustrations':

```
<% if @illustrations.size() > 0 %>
        <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
        <h3>Illustrations</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
        <%= link_to "View", {:controller => "main", :action => "show_illustrations", :illustrations => @illustrations}, :class => "btn btn-mini"%>
        </div></div>    
            <div class="search_results well-search-results">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                    <% @illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= illustration.name %></td>
                            <td><%= link_to "Show", illustration, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-mini", :style => "float:right;" %></td>
                        </tr> 
                    <% end %>
                </table>
            </div>
        <% else %>
            <h3>No Matching Illustrations</h3>
        <% end %>
```

The page that should show the grid of illustrations, titled searched_illustrations.html.erb:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well padding:0px;">
    <% @illustrations.each_slice(4) do |set| %>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <% set.each do |illustration| %>
          <div class="span3">
            <div style="text-align:center"><%= link_to image_tag(illustration.image_thumbnail_url), illustration %>
              <br />
              <%= illustration.name %><br />
              <%= link_to illustration.novel.name, illustration.novel %> - 
              <%= illustration.novel.edition %>
              <% if ! illustration.tags.empty? %>
                <br />
                <% illustration.tags.each do |tag| %>
                  <%= tag %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
           <br />
          </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <br \>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb:

```
match 'main/show_illustrations' => 'main#show_illustrations', as: :show_illustrations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad, but it's a solution:

In the search controller:

```
def show_illustrations
    @arr = params[:illustrations]
    @illustrations = Array.new

    @arr.each do |id|
        illustration = Illustration.find(id)
        @illustrations << illustration
    end

    @illustrations = Kaminari.paginate_array(@illustrations).page(params[:page]).per(20)
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it would help a lot if you were more specific about which search gem you are using, but let's assume your using `meta_search`. `meta_search`, and I believe some other search gems, return an object of class `Search`, and you need to call the `.results` method to get the search results.

Its just like you how you cant call `@users = User`, you have to call `@users = User.all`. In this case its `@listings = Listing.search(params[:search]).results.all`